# Retrieving value from Tkinter combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

Eventually I want to use the values in the comboboxes as parameters in other functions, but I think if I can just get them to print for now, that will be enough to build off of. Here's what I have so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

def ok():
    betType = betTypeVar.get()
    season = seasonVar.get()
    print(betType, season)

def CreateSimPreviousSeasonWindow():

    prevSeasonWindow = tk.Tk()

    #============= Bet Type Input =============#
    betTypeVar = tk.StringVar()

    betTypeLabel = tk.Label(prevSeasonWindow, text="Bet type:").grid(row=0,column=0)
    betTypeChosen = ttk.Combobox(prevSeasonWindow, values=['Moneyline','Total'])
    betTypeChosen.grid(row=0, column=1)

    seasonVar = tk.StringVar()
    seasonLabel = tk.Label(prevSeasonWindow, text='Season:').grid(row=1, column=0)
    seasonChosen = ttk.Combobox(prevSeasonWindow, values=['2018', '2017'])
    seasonChosen.grid(row=1,column=1)

    button = tk.Button(prevSeasonWindow, text='OK', command=ok)
    button.grid(row=2,column=0)

    prevSeasonWindow.mainloop()
```

This gives me

```
  File "C:[directory...]", line 6, in ok
    betType = betTypeVar.get()
NameError: name 'betTypeVar' is not defined
```

To me it looks pretty obvious that this error is because ok() doesn't have any parameters passed to it, so it has no idea what 'betTypeVar' is, but all the tutorials I've read do it this way, so I'm missing something. If I try actually passing ok() the arguments, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to fix in your code. First let's focus on `CreateSimPreviousSeasonWindow`:

```
betTypeVar = tk.StringVar()
seasonVar = tk.StringVar()
```

You defined two `StringVar` but you actually never used it or linked them to your `combobox` object. The correct way is to set them as a `textvaraible`:

```
betTypeChosen = ttk.Combobox(prevSeasonWindow, textvariable=betTypeVar, values=['Moneyline','Total'])
seasonChosen = ttk.Combobox(prevSeasonWindow, textvariable=seasonVar, values=['2018', '2017'])
```

Next, `NameError: name 'betTypeVar' is not defined` is due to your variables being local variables. You are trying to access the same variable across different functions. To pass them around, you need to declare `global`:

```
def ok():
    global betTypeVar, seasonVar
    betType = betTypeVar.get()
    season = seasonVar.get()
    print(betType, season)

def CreateSimPreviousSeasonWindow():
    global betTypeVar, seasonVar
    ...
```

Also I want to point out that if you just want to retrieve the values of the combobox, you don't really need to create two `StringVar`. Just `combobox.get()` already works good enough.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

def ok():
    global betTypeChosen, seasonChosen
    print (betTypeChosen.get(), seasonChosen.get())

def CreateSimPreviousSeasonWindow():
    global betTypeChosen,seasonChosen

    prevSeasonWindow = tk.Tk()

    #============= Bet Type Input =============#

    betTypeLabel = tk.Label(prevSeasonWindow, text="Bet type:").grid(row=0,column=0)
    betTypeChosen = ttk.Combobox(prevSeasonWindow,values=['Moneyline','Total'])
    betTypeChosen.grid(row=0, column=1)

    seasonLabel = tk.Label(prevSeasonWindow, text='Season:').grid(row=1, column=0)
    seasonChosen = ttk.Combobox(prevSeasonWindow, values=['2018', '2017'])
    seasonChosen.grid(row=1,column=1)

    button = tk.Button(prevSeasonWindow, text='OK', command=ok)
    button.grid(row=2,column=0)

    prevSeasonWindow.mainloop()

CreateSimPreviousSeasonWindow()
```

Comment: Thanks, the last part, with .get() works. I tried to use the first part and it runs with no errors, but when I push the OK button, nothing prints in the terminal. When I end the program though, there are a few blank rows in the terminal before the new line (the ">>>"), so it seems like it's trying to do something. The .get() method is probably better anyway though, so I'm going to try to make this work. Thanks.